# c++ pointer: overload operator++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I tried find anything about overload operator ++ for pointer, but without results.

There is my code.

```
struct Item
{
    int amount;
    Item(int a){ this->amount = a; };
    Item& operator++()
    { 
       this->amount++; 
       return *this;
    };
};


int main()
{

    Item *I = new Item(5);

    ++*I;

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any options that a could write only in main function

```
++I;
```

(sorry about my English)

Comment: You can't overload operators on non-class types.

Comment: ^ specifically a pointer

Comment: `++I` already does something, it increments the pointer.  Like it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot overload operators for pointer types.

When defining your own `operator++` the first argument to the function must be of *class-* or *enumeration-type*, as specified in `[over.inc]p1` in the C++ Standard:

> The user-defined function called `operator++` implements the prefix and postfix `++` operator. If this function is a member function with no parameters, or a non-member function with one parameter of class or enumeration type, it defines the prefix increment operator `++` for objects of that type.

---

**But I really really want to call `operator++` without having to explicitly write `*ptr`...**

And you can, but it's not the prettiest looking line of code:

```
ptr->operator++ (); // call member function `operator++`
```

---

<sub>**Note**: Instead of doing `Item *I = new Item (5); ++*I`, consider using just `Item I (5); ++I`, there's no need to use pointers in your snippet.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Just don't use a pointer (there's no need for it anyway):

```
Item I(5);
++I;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can manually write (if you REALLY want to use a pointer)

```
I->operator++();
```